# ViewModel declared as Object literals. How assign a value to observable array element?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a very simple test:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7YRDL/)

There I have declared my viewmodel in ojbect literals pattern.

Then on checkbox click, I would like to change the values of the observablearray elements.

When I try to this:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.people(), function(person) {
            console.log("was: " + person.name); 
            person.name ("Alex");
            console.log("changedto: " + person.name);  
        });
```

(note person.name ("alex"), I have js error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Property 'name' of object # is not a function '. When I change the line to 'person.name = "alex"' I have no errors but my UI does not change !

Please help me to property assign a value to the observable array element, so the change is reflected in UI.

thanks!

Comment: In your fiddle there is no array, please update your fiddle with your actual code! But according to your error message: the `name` property should be `ko.observable` on the person object in your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the properties of the objects in your array aren't observables, so they are not functions and the UI won't update with their changes.

If you change it to:

```
people : ko.observableArray([
    { name: ko.observable('Bert') },
    { name: ko.observable('Charles') },
    { name: ko.observable('Denise') }
])
```

They will then be observable and the UI will update when they are changed.

Comment: no worries I have made that mistake countless times and still sit there wondering why nothing is updating :)